# can I say 'a 300-thousand city'

Tags: nouns, numbers

I am looking for a noun meaning 'having 300 thousand inhabitants' so that I could say for example 'a 300-thousand city' instead of 'a city in which 300 thousand people live' or 'a city inhabited by 300 thousand people' etc. can I use the former form, and if not, is it possible to use another noun to do so?

Comment: English doesn't have a word corresponding to [lahk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh). The standard way to phrase this in English is to say "*A city with a population of 300,000*".

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: no.

While I’m sure you could employ Latin or Greek numerals to somehow conjure up an adjective (which is what you’re looking for, by the way—not a noun) that means ‘having 300,000’, doing so would be fairly pointless, because it would probably be a behemoth of a word, and nobody would understand it anyway.

The pithiest way I can think of to express ‘a city with 300,000 inhabitants’ is to simply call it ***a city of 300,000***. That should be understood in most contexts, even though it’s perhaps not always the most stylistically elegant phrasing.

The construction you suggest, *a 300,000 city*, is ungrammatical. It is possible to use numeral + noun as an adjunct, and in some cases this sounds perfectly natural and is elegant enough: *a five-dollar bill* or *a three-page letter* are both fine, and *one-man army* and *8/16/32-bit colour* are fixed phrases that would never be expressed differently.

But this construction absolutely *requires* that the thing counted be mentioned. Moreover, it is not a very ‘scaleable’ construction: it works fine with smaller numbers and simple nouns, but it becomes very inelegant and unidiomatic very quickly. *A 300,000-inhabitant city* is quite far beyond the limit of what this construction can handle—it is unidiomatic and cumbersome to the point of being quite difficult to understand in speech.

Comment: +1 for the simplification to the minimal, elegant "*A city of 300,000*".

Comment: "Absolutely requires" is wrong; *a ten-thousand strong army* is perfectly idiomatic, not to say time-honoured. Not sure about *a million-strong city*, though.

Comment: @TimLymington _Strong_ in that case acts as the thing being counted; I would consider it a nominalised adjective.